# How can I remove certain words from my array list? -java

Tags: java, arraylist

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class U3A4_CDCollection extends javax.swing.JFrame {
ArrayList <String> strArray = new ArrayList();

/**
 * Creates new form U3A4_CDCollection
 */
public U3A4_CDCollection() {
    initComponents();
}


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    lblTitle = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    lblName = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    txtInputName = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    togbtnInitialize = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
    togbtnRemove = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
    togbtnAdd = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
    togbtnDisplay = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    txtAreaOutput = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    lblTitle.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Sylfaen", 1, 36)); // NOI18N
    lblTitle.setText("CD Collection");

    lblName.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Sylfaen", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    lblName.setText("Title - Artist");

    txtInputName.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Sylfaen", 0, 14)); // NOI18N

    togbtnInitialize.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Sylfaen", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    togbtnInitialize.setText("Initialize");
    togbtnInitialize.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            togbtnInitializeActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    togbtnRemove.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Sylfaen", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    togbtnRemove.setText("Remove");
    togbtnRemove.setEnabled(false);
    togbtnRemove.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            togbtnRemoveActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    togbtnAdd.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Sylfaen", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    togbtnAdd.setText("Add");
    togbtnAdd.setEnabled(false);
    togbtnAdd.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            togbtnAddActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    togbtnDisplay.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Sylfaen", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    togbtnDisplay.setText("Display");
    togbtnDisplay.setEnabled(false);

    txtAreaOutput.setEditable(false);
    txtAreaOutput.setColumns(20);
    txtAreaOutput.setLineWrap(true);
    txtAreaOutput.setRows(5);
    txtAreaOutput.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(txtAreaOutput);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(34, 34, 34)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(lblName)
                        .addComponent(togbtnDisplay, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 79, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(24, 24, 24)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(togbtnInitialize)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(togbtnAdd, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 79, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addComponent(togbtnRemove))
                        .addComponent(lblTitle)
                        .addComponent(txtInputName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 350, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
            .addContainerGap(43, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(lblTitle)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(txtInputName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(lblName))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(togbtnDisplay)
                .addComponent(togbtnInitialize)
                .addComponent(togbtnRemove)
                .addComponent(togbtnAdd))
            .addGap(29, 29, 29)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 267, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(34, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void togbtnAddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    strArray.add(this.txtInputName.getText());
    System.out.println(strArray);
    this.txtAreaOutput.setText(txtAreaOutput.getText() + "\n" + strArray.get(strArray.size()));

}                                         

private void togbtnInitializeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
    togbtnAdd.setEnabled(true);
    togbtnRemove.setEnabled(true);
    togbtnDisplay.setEnabled(true);

    String[] strArray = {"Calvin Harris - Overdrive(Part 2)", "DVBBS & Borgeous - TSUNAMI", "Martin Garrix - Tremor", "Martin Garrix - Animals", "Firebeatz - Max Ammo"};
    int intArrayLength = strArray.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < intArrayLength; i++){
        this.txtAreaOutput.setText(txtAreaOutput.getText() + "\n" + strArray[i]);

    }


    togbtnInitialize.setEnabled(false);

}                                                

private void togbtnRemoveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    String strRemove = this.txtInputName.getText();
    System.out.print(strArray);
    for (int i = 0; i < strArray.size(); i++){
        if (strArray.get(i).equals(strRemove)){
            strArray.remove(strRemove);
        }
    }
    System.out.print(strArray);
}                                            

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(U3A4_CDCollection.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(U3A4_CDCollection.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(U3A4_CDCollection.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(U3A4_CDCollection.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new U3A4_CDCollection().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblName;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblTitle;
private javax.swing.JToggleButton togbtnAdd;
private javax.swing.JToggleButton togbtnDisplay;
private javax.swing.JToggleButton togbtnInitialize;
private javax.swing.JToggleButton togbtnRemove;
private javax.swing.JTextArea txtAreaOutput;
private javax.swing.JTextField txtInputName;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

I've attempted to remove a string from strArray already by doing this but when I run it, it doesn't seem to do anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Edit: Included rest of code

Comment: Have you tried strArray.remove(strRemove)? You might consider providing a runnable example which demonstrates your problem

Comment: If you print the String's you're testing to the console, what kind of output do you see? Are you sure the String's that you are testing don't contain any whitespace which may result in a false comparison? The code you've written seems fine, so it must depend on the String values that you are testing. Also, has strArray been initialized at all?

Comment: ur code is perfectly fine.Could u plz print strArray before the and after the for loop and share us the list content?

Comment: So I have 3 buttons, Initialize, add, and remove. The initialize one prints out 5 strings that are already in the strArray and did that by using String[] strArray = {5 strings}. Next I tried to add another string onto strArray using the add button and printed it out to see if it would print out everything that the initialize button outputted + the string i added onto strArray using strArray.add(this.txtInputName.getText());. It seems like the problem is i have 3 differen't strArrays within each button, therefore i can't check if a string is in strArrays. So how could I link them all together?

Comment: Just use `strArray.remove(strRemove)`. You don't even need a for loop. The method will return true if the string was found in the list, else false.

Comment: Okay @goodBadandUgly [string] printed out before the loop and after the loop it printed out [string][]

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine. Post [short but complete code example which will let us reproduce your problem](http://sscce.org/). You don't need to (and for simplicity probably shouldn't) create GUI demo application, simple console should be fine.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile...

Comment: Better, not perfect since there is still many unnecessary GUI code, but at least it lets us reproduce your problem (BTW you should probably use `JButton` instead of `JToggleButton`)

Comment: okay i'll try to change that

Answer (score 1):

You can improve readability (and performance) of your code a little by avoiding

```
area.setText(area.getText()+newText);
```

Instead you can simply use

```
area.append(newText);
```

BTW, you should probably use `JButton` instead of `JToggleButton`

---

Now first problem is that inside your `togbtnInitializeActionPerformed` you are creating local array

```
String[] strArray = {"Calvin Harris..."};
```

which has nothing to do with your field

```
ArrayList<String> strArray = new ArrayList();
```

so this list stays empty.

Maybe consider something more like

```
    strArray = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
                    "Calvin Harris - Overdrive(Part 2)",
                    "DVBBS & Borgeous - TSUNAMI", 
                    "Martin Garrix - Tremor",
                    "Martin Garrix - Animals", 
                    "Firebeatz - Max Ammo"));
    for (String value : strArray) {
        this.txtAreaOutput.append(value + "\n");
    }
```

---

Other problem is that in `togbtnAddActionPerformed` you are using

```
strArray.get(strArray.size())
```

which means that for list of size `n` you are trying to get element indexed with `n` but since elements are indexed from `0`, `n`-th element will have index `n-1` because

```
{0, 1, 2, ..., n-2, n-1} => n-elements
```

So if you want to get last element use

```
strArray.get(strArray.size()-1)
```

---

Also your `togbtnInitializeActionPerformed` method you are having unnecessary loop. Simple call

```
strArray.remove(strRemove);
```

should handle removing `strRemove` value from `strArray` list if it exists there.

Another thing is that this method lacks code which will redraw elements from list into textarea like

```
txtAreaOutput.setText("");
for (String value : strArray) {
    this.txtAreaOutput.append(value + "\n");
}
```

Comment: But when I tried 

          strArray.remove(strRemove);

I checked if strArray had anything in it by clicking the remove button and  it didn't have anything stored in the variable and in my add button it only contained strings that i added with the add button and then when i tried the initialize button it only contained the strings that i added by using the initialize button. It seems as though I have 3 different arrays and each button is adding/subtracting from their seperate arrays

Answer (score 0):

There's a remove method that accepts an object as the parameter and removes it from the list if it's in the list.

```
strArray.remove(strRemove);
```

The method returns true if the Object was deleted (meaning it was there when you called the method) and false if not, so if you want to remove all instances of the String you can do:

```
while(strArray.remove(strRemove)){}
```

which will remove all the instances of the String in the list until there aren't any more.